# React: Switch images after load

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component composed of a few images. When the user performs a action, these images need to reload.

At the moment I'm achieving this by passing a `version` property to `props` which is appended to the image path as a query parameter. When the user performs the action, this is updated and a new set of images are loaded.

The issue is, one the `version` property is updated, the images in the component clear to white and start to load individually which doesn't look very nice. What I'd like, ideally, is for the old images to remain until all the new images have loaded (possibly with a loading indicator overlaid over the component) and then switch them all out at once.

How would this be approached within React?

Comment: This might give you a idea of how you could do it: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/49369/

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: The example posted by David below is basically what I'm trying to achieve. The difference being that the new images are newly generated and wouldn't be cached.

Answer (score 1):

OK this puts a dummy image in the DOM (that should not show) and listens to it's `onLoad` event. When that fires, it will then update the src (manually, i.e. not via state) of the 'real' image element.

```
const IMG_WIDTH = 320;
const IMG_HEIGHT = 240;
const baseImageUrl = `http://loremflickr.com/${IMG_WIDTH}/${IMG_HEIGHT}`;

const pics = [
  'https://img1.wsimg.com/fos/sales/cwh/8/images/cats-with-hats-shop-02.jpg',
  'https://img1.wsimg.com/fos/sales/cwh/8/images/cats-with-hats-og-image.jpg',
  'http://www.dispatch.com/content/graphics/2015/05/08/2-cats-in-hats-crafts-art-gof11etjd-1crafts-cats-in-hats-jpeg-03592-jpg.jpg',
  'http://www.dispatch.com/content/graphics/2015/05/08/2-cats-in-hats-crafts-art-gof11etjd-1crafts-cats-in-hats-jpeg-0b417-jpg.jpg',
  'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/cNycdfFEgBc/maxresdefault.jpg'
];

// this should really be hidden
// leaving it visible for, um, visibility
const hiddenImageStyle = {
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
};

class Image extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onNextImageLoad = this.onNextImageLoad.bind(this);
    this.nextImageUrl = pics[0];
  }

  onNextImageLoad() {
    this.visibleImgEl.src = this.nextImageUrl;
  }

  render() {
    this.nextImageUrl = pics[this.props.imageIndex % 5];

    return (
      <div>
        <img
          ref={el => this.visibleImgEl = el}
          width={IMG_WIDTH}
          height={IMG_HEIGHT}
          src={pics[0]}
        />

        <img
          style={hiddenImageStyle}
          src={this.nextImageUrl}
          onLoad={this.onNextImageLoad}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ImageController extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.goToNextImage = this.goToNextImage.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      imageIndex: 0,
    };
  }

  goToNextImage() {
    this.setState({imageIndex: this.state.imageIndex + 1});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Image imageIndex={this.state.imageIndex} />

        <button onClick={this.goToNextImage}>
          Next image
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(<ImageController/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

jsbin: https://jsbin.com/ramoxa/2

Comment: On Chrome, it goes to white while the new image is being loaded. Is it possible that the images in your case are cached by the browser, which is why you wouldn't notice any flickering?

Comment: OK updated my answer, I don't get the white flash (the old image stays till the new one is loaded, even with cache off and network throttling) so it's a bit hard to test.